# Hotwire/Turbo with rails : paging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, hotwire

I would like to implement a simple paging system with turbo

```rb
<h1> Title </h1>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "page" do %>
  current page : <%= params[:page] %>
<% end %>
<p> other content </p>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "next" do %>
  <a href="?page=<%= params[:page].to_i + 1 %>">
   Next page
  </a>
<% end %>
```

and GET `?page=1`
return (the controller render a partial when params[:page] is present)

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "page" do %>
  current page : <%= params[:page] %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "next" do %>
  <a href="?page=<%= params[:page].to_i + 1 %>">
   Next page
  </a>
<% end %>
```

but only the `#next` element get reload,
and when I add `target: "page"` to the #next , only the first turbo-frame get reloaded

can we put multiple target to a turbo_frame_tag or whats the right way to do this

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `turbo frame` has been replaced just by only one frame (from response) at the time so far. If you want to replace multiple frames, you could use `turbo stream`.

So either you could move the paging `next` frame into the `page` frame and response only the `page` frame:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag "page" do %>
  current page : <%= params[:page] %>

  <p> other content </p>
  
  <a href="?page=<%= params[:page].to_i + 1 %>">
    Next page
  </a>
<% end %>
```

Or use `turbo-stream`

```rb
<h1> Title </h1>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "page" do %>
  current page : <%= params[:page] %>
<% end %>
<p> other content </p>
<%= turbo_frame_tag "next" do %>
  <%= button_to "next", query_page_path(page: params[:page].to_i + 1) %>
<% end %>

# pages_controller
def query
  # query pages
  respond_to do |format|
    format.turbo_stream { }
  end
end

# pages/query.turbo_stream.erb
<%= turbo_stream.replace "page" %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_stream.replace "next" %>
<% end %>
```

reference: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/56

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "page", target "next" do %> 
current page 
<%= params[page] %> 
<% end %> 
<%= turbo_frame_tag "next" do %> 
<a href="?page=<%= params[page].to_i + 1 %>">Next page</a> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: unless I am mistaken, It does not work, the turbo_frame_tag "page" does not update